# Trying to update label phone number in Address Book

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, phone-number

All of the phone numbers stored at address book have a label like:
"home", "work", "home fax", etc.
I need to change the label of a specific contact putting a custom label named "ATM".

I got this error message:

```
"Assertion failed: (((ABCMultiValue *)multiValue)->flags.isMutable), function ABMultiValueReplaceLabelAtIndex, file /SourceCache/AddressBook_Sim/AddressBook-796.6/ABMultiValue.c, line 118."
```

This is my code, there is a comment where I got excepton:

```
- (void)displayPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
    NSString* name = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    self.firstName.text = name;
    NSString* phone = nil;
    NSString* lbl = nil;
    NSString* newLbl = @"ATM";

    ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person,
                                                 kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0) {
        phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)
        ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);

        lbl = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)
        ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);

        //*** HERE IS THE PROBLEM ***
        ABMultiValueReplaceLabelAtIndex(phoneNumbers, CFSTR("ATM"), 0);

        NSLog(@"  - %@ (%@)", phone, lbl);
    } else {
        phone = @"[None]";
        lbl = @"[None]";
        newLbl = @"[None]";
    }

    CFRelease(phoneNumbers);
}
```

How can I change the label of that phone number?

Comment: People, just to complement my method "displayPerson" came from this example:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/QuickStart.html

Answer (score 2):

I Found a solution:
The code below is working fine:

```
- (void)displayPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
```

{

```
ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef record = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(ab, ABRecordGetRecordID(person));
CFErrorRef *error = NULL;

ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(record,kABPersonPhoneProperty);
ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMV = ABMultiValueCreateMutableCopy(phoneNumbers);


for(CFIndex i=0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumberMV); i++){
    NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumberMV,i);
    //NSSlog(@"phoneNumber = %@", phoneNumber);

    if ([@"1128558994" isEqualToString:phoneNumber]) {
        //now delete it!!! ;-)
        /*
         NSSlog(@"phoneNumbers = %@",phoneNumbers);
         NSSlog(@"index = %d", i);
         */

        //BOOL didRemove = ABMultiValueRemoveValueAndLabelAtIndex(phoneNumberMV,i);

        BOOL didChanged = ABMultiValueReplaceLabelAtIndex(phoneNumberMV, (CFStringRef)@"0870", i);
        NSLog(@"didRemove = %@\n", (didChanged ? @"TRUE" : @"FALSE"));

        BOOL didSet = ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumberMV, nil);
        NSLog(@"didSet = %@\n", (didSet ? @"TRUE" : @"FALSE"));

        //and save it!
        BOOL didSave = ABAddressBookSave(ab, (CFErrorRef *) error);

        NSLog(@"didSave = %@\n", (didSave ? @"TRUE" : @"FALSE"));
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"ABAddressBookSaveError = %@", error);
        }
    }
}
CFRelease(ab);
```

}